# Get the details of user by comma separated user_id from Firebase

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am working with `Firebase` database for my application. I have one scenario where I need to display list of `Call` detail screen where each user's call history should be display. In `firebase` database I have two main node

Here is the image of the both node.

**1) Users** - user node have user related data with basic details of name,email and other stuff

[image]

**2) Calls** - user's call history each call have `user_id` which is related to in `Users` node for his/her basic details.

[image]

Now I want to details `(first_name,last_name,email)` of `user_id` from `Calls` node each entry or each object. So is there any solution for getting details via passing a `comma seprated` `user_id` list and getting its details from `Firebase`. Or is there a any other solution to fetching basic details.

Thank you in advanced if any one have faced this and provide a solution on this.

Comment: get Calls table data and use observeSingleEventOfType to get user table data.

Comment: @priyadharshini, here is only 2 data in call but in the case where i have 1000 data with different users data that time I have to call user table data with 1000 users information using loop for iterating each objects.??? Not proper solution i guess.

Comment: then update firstname and lastname like user_id in calls table

Comment: so if profile data is updated I need to update calls table with each object ?? lolz